# Always the default implementation of protocol gets called even after implementing the method in class extension in an XCTest file

Tags: swift, mocking, protocols, xctest

I have a protocol

```
protocol SomeProtocol { func method() }
```

and its implementation

```
extension SomeProtocol {func method(){--implementation--}}
```

In build target i have a class confirming to this protocol

```
class SomeClass: SomeProtocol { func doSomething() { method() } }
```

What i want is i want to have a different implementation of the protocol method in my test target, in my XCTest file. For that what i did was i extended the SomeClass and wrote my implementation there.

```
extension SomeClass {func method(){--other implementation--} }
```

But it never got called while executing test cases. Always the method in build target, the default implementation, was getting called.

Please advice what i should be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. I was using `@testable import MYProject.` The above method wont work if you are using this. If you are adding all of your project files instead of using the import, then the above method works.

ref: https://medium.com/@hartwellalex/protocol-extensions-and-shared-dependency-injection-in-swift-an-alternative-to-singletons-68934dee6998

Comment: Great workaround! To see more about this case, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53487613/dynamic-dispatching-protocol-extension-doesnt-work-multiple-targets/53488560#53488560