# Dynamic dispatching protocol extension doesn't work multiple targets

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, swift-extensions, dynamic-dispatch, swift-modules

This is my code in my main target(so not the test target):

```
protocol ProtocolA {
    func dontCrash()
}

extension ProtocolA {
    func dontCrash() {
        fatalError()
    }

    func tryCrash() {
        dontCrash()
    }
}

class MyClass: ProtocolA {}
```

In my test target (so different target), I got this code:

```
import XCTest
@testable import Project

extension MyClass {
    func dontCrash() {
        print("I dont crash")
    }
}

class ProjectTests: XCTestCase {
    func testExample() {
        MyClass().tryCrash()
    }
}
```

It crashes. Why it doesn't use the dynamic dispatching mechanism? `MyClass` has it's own implementation of `dontCrash()`, I expect that one to fire.

Comment: You're calling `tryCrash` in the test case.

Comment: @CraigSiemens Well... Yes! But what does tryCrash() do? It calls the default dontCrash() method defined in the protocol extension, not it's own implementation of MyClass.

Comment: [Related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46123963/redeclaring-members-in-an-extension-hides-the-original-member-sometimes-why)

Comment: Running this by just calling `MyClass().tryCrash()` in a standalone Swift file. It prints "I dont crash"

Comment: @Alexander I updated my question a bit, maybe it was unclear, but the 2 codes are in a different .swift file (and a different target)

Comment: @Rob Still crashing... The 2 codes live in different targets

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49522720/1271826

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Project` module declares `MyClass`'s conformance to `ProtocolA`.

Swift implements that conformance using a data structure called a “protocol witness table”. For each method declared by the protocol, the witness table contains a function that calls the actual implementation of the method for the conforming type.

To be concrete, there is a witness table for the conformance of `MyClass` to `ProtocolA`. That witness table contains a function for the `dontCrash` method declared by `ProtocolA`. That function in the witness table calls the `MyClass` `dontCrash` method.

You can see the function from the protocol witness table in the stack trace when your test case hits `fatalError`:

```
#8  0x00000001003ab9d9 in _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) ()
#9  0x00000001000016fc in ProtocolA.dontCrash() at /Users/rmayoff/TestProjects/Project/Project/AppDelegate.swift:11
#10 0x0000000100001868 in protocol witness for ProtocolA.dontCrash() in conformance MyClass ()
#11 0x000000010000171e in ProtocolA.tryCrash() at /Users/rmayoff/TestProjects/Project/Project/AppDelegate.swift:15
#12 0x00000001030f1987 in ProjectTests.testExample() at /Users/rmayoff/TestProjects/Project/ProjectTests/ProjectTests.swift:12
#13 0x00000001030f19c4 in @objc ProjectTests.testExample() ()
```

Frame #10 is the call from `tryCrash` to the function in the protocol witness table. Frame #9 is the call from the protocol witness table function to the actual implementation of `dontCrash`.

Swift emits the protocol witness table in the module that declares the conformance. So, in your case, the witness table is part of the `Project` module.

Your override of `dontCrash` in your test bundle cannot change the contents of the witness table. It's too late for that. The witness table was fully defined when Swift generated the `Project` module.

Here's why it has to be this way:

Suppose I'm the author of the `Project` module and you're just a user of it. When I wrote the `Project` module, I knew calling `MyClass().dontCrash()` would call `fatalError`, and I relied on this behavior. In many places inside `Project`, I called `MyClass().dontCrash()` specifically because I knew it would call `fatalError`. You, as a user of `Project`, don't know how much `Project` depends on that behavior.

Now you use the `Project` module in your app, but you retroactively change `MyClass().dontCrash()` to not call `fatalError`. Now all those places where `Project` calls `MyClass().dontCrash()` don't behave in the way that I expected when I wrote the `Project` module. You have broken the `Project` module, even though you didn't change the source code of the `Project` module or any of the modules that `Project` imports.

It's critical to the correct operation of the `Project` module that this not happen. So the only way to change what `MyClass().dontCrash()` means (when called from inside the `Project` module) is to change the source code of the `Project` module itself (or change the source code of something that `Project` imports).

Comment: Thank you for your amazing answer! So we can say: Per module we have a immutable protocol witness table? It would be better if Swift gave a compile error for the extension in the tests target, since there is no chance it will ever be executed though.